# How to highlighted text in the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 tab-bottom">
                    <div class="tab-bottom-img"><img width="380" height="380" src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/2-380x380.png" class="attachment-news wp-post-image" alt="2"> </div>
                        <div class="tab-bottom-content" style="display: block;">
                            <div>
                            <p class="title_bottom">SED PERSPICIATIS</p>
                            <p class="content_bottom"></p><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit<br>
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,<br>
totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore<br>
veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt<br>
explicabo.</p>
<p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.tab-bottom {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
.tab-bottom-img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.tab-bottom-img img{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* opacity: 0.5; */
}
.tab-bottom:hover{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Unfortunately font can not see very well ... I would like to be like in the image below ..

[image]

The font used is:`Archivo Narrow / Bold` for title

Can you give me please how to solve this problem?
Where it comes from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try and set opacity: 1.0 to .content_bottom in your css.

Comment: Is your code here in error? `<p class="content_bottom"></p><p>Sed ut perspiciatis` you are prematurely closing the `content_bottom` tag and so there aren't any styles being applied to the content that starts with `Sed ut perspiciatis`....

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your CSS:

```
.title_bottom, .content_bottom {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

so that within the text area the font is full colour and solid, rather than semi-translucent.

You may also want to improve this part:

```
<p class="content_bottom"></p><p>Sed ut
```

because the class is only being applied to the first, empty, paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set full opacity to the content inside the particular division. Try this

```
.content_bottom , .title_bottom{
    opacity: 1.0;
    color:red; //the code for the color you have used in the title
}
```

Comment: I added your code style and nothing changes ... have added anything?

Comment: You also need to set the color to the particular red color code

Comment: I added, looking after your code in main.css and you will gasi..din Unfortunately nothing changes ... I put wrong?

Comment: In your website i cannot see the overlay color on hover ( the beige) , is that what you are trying to add ?

Comment: At line 11049..there